# jenkins cucumber jvm reports plugin java screenshots

Tags: jenkins-plugins, cucumber-jvm

I'm using this plugin for cucumber, and I saw that if one or more steps are failed you have the screenshot on the report of that step.
Is there a way to have the screenshots for each step also if they are not failed?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is not considered a good practice due to performance overhead however you can do it using "afterstep"
hooks.